# Printing to console with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, lambda

I am attempting to create a new thread for every line in a txt file. These threads will be running a loop forever therefor they will never end. When creating these threads I want to print to console

```
Running: dhjkshdkfsdadfas
Running: fdjkbflsdfsfsfsf
Running: dfjklsfjnlkdsfsf
```

But I get this distorted output

```
Running: Running: kjfdugewrfuhoidfsujhisdf
Running: Running: fbjklsdfhilsedfhiosefhilhikldfjlsdilsdfjsdfjhsdfRunning: Running: bjhklsdfhklsdfhklsdfklhsRunning: ihlfsdjildsfiljfsdjisdfjdfshklsdfkjldsfjklsdfjkl
jklsdfjdsfjsdfjsdfjdsfsd
```

I am running the current code

```
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

colorama.init()

def host(link):
    print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "Running: " + Fore.MAGENTA + link)
    time.sleep(1000) #ment to be forever

def main():
    print("TEST")
    time.sleep(3)

    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1000)

    for link in open("links.txt","r+").readlines():
        threading.Thread(target=lambda : host(link.replace("\n",""))).start()

main()
```

I have tried removing the lambda but that seems to lead to only running one thread at a time.

the links.txt file looks something like

```
kjfdugewrfuhoidfsujhisdf
fbjklsdfhilsedfhiosefhil
bjhklsdfhklsdfhklsdfklhs
ihlfsdjildsfiljfsdjisdfj
hikldfjlsdilsdfjsdfjhsdf
jklsdfjdsfjsdfjsdfjdsfsd
dfshklsdfkjldsfjklsdfjkl
```

Comment: I think you want to serialize the calls to `print()` by acquiring a mutex before calling `print()` and then releasing it afterwards, as shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311157/131930

Comment: Or queue the "link"s, and have a single thread dequeue & print each one.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is many threads are printing at the same exact time. You need to block that by using a printing queue or threading semaphore or Gil lock.

[queue implementation with threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) in this code they print without queue. in real tasks, some process finishes at the same time. and also it's better if you used the same technique for inputs. sometimes without a queue, two threads may take the same input.

[semaphore question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688424/python-threads-are-printing-at-the-same-time-messing-up-the-text-output)

[Gil lock](https://www.guru99.com/python-multithreading-gil-example.html)