# Python threading, some printing messages turn concatenated in one line

Tags: python, multithreading

Here I have a code containing a simple class printing something. I want to multithread it.

```
import threading
import time
import random


class Useless:
    def __init__(self, numb):
        self.numb = numb

    def printing(self):
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.05, 0.09))
        print(f'number {self.numb} is being printed God knows what for...')

    def main_loop(self):
        for _ in range(5):
            self.printing()


obj_1 = Useless(1)
obj_2 = Useless(2)

proc_1 = threading.Thread(target=obj_1.main_loop, args=())
proc_2 = threading.Thread(target=obj_2.main_loop, args=())

proc_1.start()
proc_2.start()
```

**The number of threads is arbitrary, so I can create more proc_. This is a key requirement!**

But sometimes I receive a weird printing results like this:

```
number 2 is being printed God knows what for...number 1 is being printed God knows what for...

number 1 is being printed God knows what for...
number 2 is being printed God knows what for...
number 1 is being printed God knows what for...
number 2 is being printed God knows what for...
number 1 is being printed God knows what for...
number 2 is being printed God knows what for...
number 1 is being printed God knows what for...
number 2 is being printed God knows what for...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You see sometimes some printed messages mix together and printed in one line but I would like them to be separate.

Probably subprocess pipe can help with it but I don't know how to implement it here. Probably Asyncio can solve it. So I want threads to be executed simultaneously (almost simultaneously within one core) but to have printed messages separated.

Comment: Well, what did you expect? You only have one stdout. Have you tried using a lock?

Comment: no, I haven't. How to insert lock here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Threads are printing at the same time messing up the text output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688424/python-threads-are-printing-at-the-same-time-messing-up-the-text-output)

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no guarantees (this is highly OS specific), you can hardly send newline to stdout instead of python handling this

```
def printing(self):
    print(f'number {self.numb} is being printed God knows what for...\n', end='')
```

But I still do not recommend using this approach as it does not solve problem. Much appropriate way is to use some buffers and flush them synchronously

Comment: As far as I am trying different approaches I found a probable solution. if I am using os.system('echo <my message>') or subprocess.run(['echo', '<my message>'], capture_output=False) this problem doesn't show up. It may be occasional perception, after a number of tries the problem may appear back but now it doesn't. I explain it to myself like this commands operate with OS directly and OS sequence it by it self. I am not sure that's true.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the `flush` keyword args into print function, and no print will be concatenated

```
print("Hello world", flush=True)
```